# Keep directory name when copying in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following script:

```
import shutil

src = "C:\test"
dest = "C:\copied_test"
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

This script works for copying the contents of `C:\test` to `C:\copied_test`. How do I have to change my script so that `C:\test` will be copied to `C:\copied_test\test`, i.e. the directory name shall be kept while copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the `dest` directory name based on the `src` so that it become `c:\copied_test`.

```
import os  # <----
import shutil

src = r"C:\test"
dest = r"C:\copied_test"
dest = os.path.join(dest, os.path.basename(src))  # <---
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

BTW, you need to escape `\` or use raw string literal. Otherwise, `\t` become TAB character instead of `\` and `t`.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code is wrong. You should escape the backslashes (`'C:\\test'`) or use this trick desinged for regex: `r'C:\test'`.

With that clear, I guess `dest = "C:\\copied_test\\test"` is not the answer you are looking for?

You want to use the name of the source directory without having to type it in? Take a look at these methods which can help:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join